# Make multidimensional array unique php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My array looks like this:

> Array (
>
> ```
>     [1] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [id] => 225
>             [user_id] => 1
>             [name] => Blue Quilted Leather Jacket by Minusey - $499
>
>         )
>
>     [2] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [id] => 222
>             [user_id] => 1
>             [name] => Darling New Bathtub by Duravit - $6300
>
>         )
>    [3] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [id] => 222
>             [user_id] => 1
>             [name] => Darling New Bathtub by Duravit - $6300
>
>         )
> ```
>
> )

I have an array of products that I need to make sure are unique. Need to make this array unique by id. These array are generated by pushing value.

I'm trying to solve this for more than a week now, but I dont get it to work. I know it should be easy...but anyway - I don't get it :D

Comment: You should check in array before pushing if id is present there.

Comment: Is there anyway to check after pushing and make array unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
$input = array ('1' => array(
            'id' => 225,
            'user_id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Blue Quilted Leather Jacket by Minusey - $499'

        ),
        '2' => array(
                'id' => 222,
                'user_id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Darling New Bathtub by Duravit - $6300'

        ),
        '3' => array(
                'id' => 222,
                'user_id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Darling New Bathtub by Duravit - $6300'

        )                   
  );    

    $UniqueArray = array();
    foreach($input as $key=>$value){   // rebuild your array    
        //$id = $value['id']; //build array with unique key value
        $id = $value->id; //object
        $UniqueArray[$id] = $value;
    }

   print_r($UniqueArray);
```

**output:**

```
   Array
   (
        [225] => Array
        (
                [id] => 225
                [user_id] => 1
                [name] => Blue Quilted Leather Jacket by Minusey - $499
        )

        [222] => Array
        (
                [id] => 222
                [user_id] => 1
                [name] => Darling New Bathtub by Duravit - $6300
        )

   )
```

Comment: the  value in the array are in stdClass Object.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to loop through the products and save which you encountered. If a product has already been found, just skip it.

```
<?php
function array_unique_by_key($array, $key = 'id') {
    $found = array(); // Encountered IDs
    $out = array(); // Output array

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $value)) throw new Exception('Can\'t find key "' . $key . '"');
        $id = $value[$key];

        // If already encountered, skip
        if (in_array($id, $found)) continue;

        // Otherwise, add to found values and to output array
        $found[] = $id;
        $out[] = $value;
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Usage:

```
$unique_products = array_unique_by_key($your_products, 'id');
```

Comment: Small syntax error fixed. Algo tested with input data provided, works as expected

Answer (score 2):

try this simple code

```
$arr_new = array();
$arr_temp_ids = array();
foreach($your_array as $key=>$arr_obj)
{
    $arr_val = get_object_vars($arr_obj);
    if(!isset($arr_temp_ids[$arr_val['id']]))
    {
        $arr_new[] = $arr_obj;
        $arr_temp_ids[$arr_val['id']] = true;
    }
}
var_dump($arr_new); // resultant array
```

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object error in the following line.   if(!isset($arr_temp_ids[$arr_val->id]))